# Partial Least Square Regression using R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm new to R. I want to use the "pls" package to do Partial Least Square Analysis on my data.

The data information is design elements, whether exist or not, in 0 and 1 and the last column contains the emotion score. I want to find the design elements that contribute to the emotion.

From example that I found on the internet, I need to call

```
> plsr(density ~ NIR, 6, data=yarn, validation="CV")
```

When I try this:

> plsr(density ~ NIR, 6, data=mydata, validation="CV")

I get this error:

```
Error: object 'NIR' not found
```

How do I call the function correctly using my data?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You get the error message because your data doesn't contain columns NIR, you have to use names of variables in your data.

Comment: Can you double check your pastebin link? It doesn't seem to be the one that you are describing.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (I downloaded your pastebin and saved it as a file called "junk.dat")

```
dat <- read.csv("junk.dat")
library("pls")
summary(plsr(Adorable~.,data=dat))
```

The formula `Adorable~.` says that `Adorable` (your last column name) is the response variable and that all of the remaining columns in the data frame should be used as predictors.